# RSpec loading is extremely slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm doing a Rails 3.2 Upgrade from Rails 2.3, and along with it going to new versions of gems like RSpec.

It's worth noting that my app is extremely large:

```
$ rake stats
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| Name                 | Lines |   LOC | Classes | Methods | M/C | LOC/M |
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
| Total                | 132568 | 96987 |    1108 |    7078 |   6 |    11 |
+----------------------+-------+-------+---------+---------+-----+-------+
  Code LOC: 55656     Test LOC: 41331     Code to Test Ratio: 1:0.7
```

Day to day, I'm using zeus, which has the test environment booted in about 20 seconds, and takes about 40 minutes to run the build.

However if I run

```
$ rspec
```

It takes 4 minutes and 53 seconds just to get started, and then crawls from there.

My spec helper isn't doing anything crazy. THe only thing I've really removed is rspec/autorun, which is required to keep zeus from double-executing everything.

```
# spec_helper.rb
ENV["Rails.env"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/given'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'capybara/rspec/matchers'
require 'debugger'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.global_fixtures = :users, :roles
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"

  def (ActionDispatch::Integration::Session).fixture_path
    RSpec.configuration.fixture_path
  end
end
```

EDIT: For the record, rake spec works just fine.

Comment: Odd - that is less code than an app I work on and it takes substantially less time to get going. Maybe use ruby-prof to see where the time is going?

Answer (score 1):

The key was `ENV["Rails.env"]`, which isn't a correctly formed environment variable, and it was making everything go crazy. Search and replace gone wrong.

Comment: what's the solution ?